# Javascript sum not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum

I am working on a code to calculate the total minutes based on a table of Hours minutes and seconds.

I have been eating my nervs and can't figure out why the values are wrong, the hour field get's multiplied by 600 instead of 60, minutes add up wrong as well, seems to be a total mess.

Here is my code

```
<table width="90%"><tr>
<td><input size="4" type="text" name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>hrs"  />   </td>
<td><input size="4" type="text" name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>mins" /></td>
<td><input size="4" type="text" name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>secs" /></td>
<td><input size="10" type="text" name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_name ); ?>" id="    <?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>" class="attachments attachments-field attachments-field-<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_name ); ?> attachments-field-<?php esc_attr_e(  $field->field_id ); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->value ); ?>" readonly/></td>
</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hours</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Minutes</td>    <td>&nbsp;Seconds</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Audio Minutes</td></tr></table>
```

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>hrs"],input[name="<?php   esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>mins"],input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id );  ?>secs"]').change(function()
    {
        var sum = parseFloat($('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>hrs"]').val() * 60) + parseFloat(($('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>mins"]').val()) + parseFloat($('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>secs"]').val() / 60)).toFixed(2) 
        $('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_name ); ?>"]').val(parseFloat(sum));
    })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: " ... seems to be a total mess ... " -- that's exactly what the code is, too.

Comment: @Ioan add some indentation and I may be willing to help

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not your server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are in the wrong place. Your code says:

```
parseFloat($('input[name=fieldname]').val() * 60)
```

It should say:

```
parseFloat($('input[name=fieldname]').val()) * 60
```

(Same advice for the seconds computation with the division by 60.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my resuts are still way off. It works fine with each individual conversion (hrs, secs), but in the total rather than a sum of minutes I get the values concatenated.   2 hours and 10 minutes become 12010 minutes instead of 130

Comment: If your values are concatenating, that means JS believes they are strings. I'd say you still have a paren problem somewhere in that case. Code in the form `parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c)` should never concatenate.

Comment: I'd double check your `toFixed()` - it returns a string value. The expression `parseFloat("3") + parseFloat("4").toFixed(2)` returns `34.00`, not `7.00`. Again, misplaced parens.